# Joining a table after a self join on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a total of two tables, one that is called market_orders, and the other called item_names. Currently in the below code I am only using market_orders table and doing an inner join back to the same table.

The output of the way this code is now is perfect however a.item_id is in "Non readable english". This is why i created the table item_names that has all the same item_ids as the table being used below, but then it also has a column named item_names that contains "Readable english". I am having trouble joining the new table item_names onto what I have already.

```
select a.item_id,
case when b.price > a.price then (b.price - a.price) Else 'false' END as Sellable
from market_orders a
inner join market_orders b on a.item_id = b.item_id



where a.location = 4002
and b.location = 3003
and a.enchantment_level = 3
and b.enchantment_level = 3
and a.quality_level = 1
and b.quality_level = 1
group by item_id order by  sellable
```

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of code or data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There's nothing special about joining with additional tables. Just add another `inner join`.

Comment: `inner join item_names AS n on a.item_id = n.item_id` and then add `n.item_name` to the `SELECT` list.

Comment: @barmar when I do this it returns errors around my case statement.

Comment: You probably forgot a comma or something like that.

Comment: `select a.item_id,n.item_id,
case when b.price > a.price then (b.price - a.price) Else 'false' END as Sellable
from market_orders a
inner join market_orders b on a.item_id = b.item_id
inner join item_names AS n on a.item_id = n.item_id


where a.location = 4002
and b.location = 3003
and a.enchantment_level = 3
and b.enchantment_level = 3
and a.quality_level = 1
and b.quality_level = 1
group by item_id order by  sellable`

Comment: Your *case expression* is flawed, you can't return *different* data types, you'll get an implicit cast.

Comment: There's no syntax error in that, I don't know why you got an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `inner join` with the `item_names` table, and add the name to the `select` list.

```
select a.item_id, n.item_names,
    case 
        when b.price > a.price then (b.price - a.price) 
        Else 'false' 
    END as Sellable
from market_orders a
inner join market_orders b on a.item_id = b.item_id
inner join item_names n on a.item_id = n.item_id
where a.location = 4002
    and b.location = 3003
    and a.enchantment_level = 3
    and b.enchantment_level = 3
    and a.quality_level = 1
    and b.quality_level = 1
group by a.item_id order by  sellable
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/073587/2)

Comment: for some reason copying yours over does not throw an error now it just returns a query of 0 instead

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: This is the current output prior to adding the new table  https://imgur.com/a/UvQrkSE  After the new table I would want a 3rd column that has Item_names,

Comment: The only reason you would get zero results when adding that join is if there are no rows in the `item_names` table with matching `item_id`.

Comment: the item_id in both tables match. The item_name is unique to the table specifically. Would I need to change something in my tables. I figured since they were joined on the item_id that match on both tables that this would work this way

Comment: I asked you to post sample data. Post it as text not a screenshot, or create a sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78cb69/1/0      I included both scenarios of which I had originally and then what you listed. I am trying to get the item_names to appear in the output for each row that meets the criteria

Comment: There's no `item_id = 'T6_ARMOR_LEATHER_SET3@3'` in `item_names`. It has `T6_ARMOR_LEATHER_SET3` without `@3` at the end.

Comment: And most of the `item_id` in `item_names` have an extra space at the beginning.

Comment: There's no `T6_ARMOR_LEATHER_UNDEAD@3` in `item_names`. There's `' T5_ARMOR_LEATHER_SET3@3'`

Comment: I only put a few samples of the data in, in the database all the item names are in there, Maybe the problem would be the extra space.

Comment: If you want the example to work, you have to put in data that matches. Here's a version that works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/073587/2